# Transformer safety concern

Tags: transformer, coil, arc

I have a a transformer for my speaker (230VAC -> 9VAC). The primary of the transformer is basically a coil.

Is it not dangerous to pull out the transformer from the outlet?

I know that in coils if you suddenly force open circuit high voltage can appears..

Comment: A coil yes, a transformer no.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the point on the waveform you disconnect at, there's some energy stored in the magnetic field in the core, which will dissipate through whatever circuits are present in the windings. Since the secondary is still connected, that will continue to conduct until the remaining emf falls below the presumably rectified input voltage. No high spikes would be generated. If the output is also open circuited there'll be some arcing on disconnection, but it's generally small, and will have ended in milliseconds, long before you can get the plug out far enough to touch any pins.